# C Programming - Left shift with Switch statement error

Tags: c, switch-statement

im trying to implement the shift operators in the switch statement but im having trouble getting output.
im trying to do a simple left shift something like '12 << 2' which should return '12 << 2: 48'
heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void shift(){
    char op = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char buffer[1024];
    int iCont = -1;
    char c1 = 0;
    char c2 = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("\ninput: ");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %c%c %d", &x, &c1, &c2, &y)){}
            switch (op)
            {
            case '<<': printf("%d %c1%c %d = %d", x, c1, c2, y, x << y);
                break;
            case '>>': printf("%d %c1%c %d = %d", x, c1, c2, y, x >> y);
            default:
                break;
            }
        } while (iCont);

}
```

Comment: You're not setting `op` or changing `iCont` in the loop, and you probably don't want to compare a `char` variable to a 2-char literal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While it's nice you posted your code (and went to the trouble of formatting it correctly - thanks!), you really aren't asking a question. You say "im having trouble getting output", but you don't say what "trouble" means. Since we're not [mind readers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172661), it helps if you explain what "trouble" you're having, what's "not working", or what "an error" is specifically.

Comment: Where is the question? Has someone stolen the question? :D

Comment: I've reverted your question.  Please don't post a question and then remove its content (even if the question could have been asked better).  Doing so makes the existing answers nonsensical and undermines searchability.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `op` contains the value `0`. You are switching on the value op which is never assigned a value other than 0.

Also single quotes are for characters. `'<<'` doesn't make a lot of sense, since you have two characters in single quotes.

Comment: Actually `'<<'` is a multi-character constant. It's legal, but non-portable (the value is implementation-defined), and it makes very little sense in this context anyway.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's why I didn't say it's an error, it just doesn't make much sense :)

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is not a character. Neither is `>>`. How can `op`, which is a character, ever equal either of those?

Comment: This isn't actually the problem (the problem is that `op` is initialized to `0` and then never changed in the code), but it also doesn't really qualify as an answer (since it isn't - it's a question you're asking the poster). Not downvoting - just sayin'. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: He asked why his code doesn't work. Any defect in the code sufficient to prevent it from working is an acceptable answer. That `<<` is not a character (and he treats it like one) is a defect in his code sufficient to prevent it from working.

Comment: I guess I don't agree. :-) The fact that `op` is set to zero and never changed but is used to determine the path of the `switch` is the problem; what's contained in the branches taken in the switch is meaningless if you never get to that point. "Mail never gets to my house even though it's addressed to `1 A Street, Paris France`". "But you live in `London England`". "So? It's addressed to `1 A Street`."

Comment: @KenWhite: There are multiple problems with this code. Even if `op` was initialized correctly, it still couldn't match the `switch` statement. Not understanding how to specify character constants for a switch/case is a fundamental misunderstanding of the language. Fixing the initialization of `op` is rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic. The illogical switch/case is the iceberg. (Think about which error an experienced programmer might make and routinely debug and which indicates a misunderstanding.)

Comment: My point is that *no matter what the other problems are*, they don't matter if the code could never get there. Think about my last comment - it doesn't matter if they spell your last name wrong if it never gets to you to see. To paraphrase you: "How can `op`,  which is character, ever equal anything other than the zero you assigned to it and never changed?"

Comment: @KenWhite: Right, but that's a minor code bug. It's trivial to debug and fix. The code reflects a huge defect in the fundamental understanding of the language, and fixing that is *way* more important than the trivial bug.

Comment: The fundamental bug you keep talking about is moot if the one prior to that isn't fixed first. I think we're at an impasse here;if I take you literally, I should downvote your answer as being incorrect, and if I try to follow your ultimate meaning I shoud just go on and i9gnore it. I guess (althought I think I disagreee), I'll give you the benefit of the doubt).

Answer (score 0):

The control of the switch statement, `op` must be equal to one of the switch statement's cases for the case to run. Since `op` is initialized to 0 and doesn't change, it won't ever equal `'>>'` or `'<<'` and hence neither of the cases will execute.

Secondly, your loop doesn't really make much sense either since you seem to only want to shift once. Even if you do want the loop there, it will only undergo one iteration in the code above since `iCont` is initialized to -1, which evaluates to false in the `while(iCont)` line.

Finally, as said in the other answers you don't want to compare a char (`op`) to a multi-character constant.

You can easily fix this issue by setting `op` somewhere in the code. You could also change `op` to an integer and make the case statement integer based, like:

```
switch(op)
{ case 0: //left shift
break;
case 1: //right shift
break;}
```

Comment: I understand by what you said about the 'you don't want to compare a char (op) to a MC constance which in this case is '<<' and '>>'
I'm not quite sure when u said 'setting op somewhere in the code' after changing the op to an int.

Comment: Good. So, what exactly is your issue with the code you posted and how can we help you solve it?